# Como criar uma chave estrangeira em uma tabela onde já exista dados, no EntityFramework com Code-First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, code-first

Tenho um sistema já em produção do qual o cliente pediu uma modificação.

A modificação é a criação de uma tabela FUNCIONÁRIOS que se relacionará com a tabela MOVIMENTAÇÃO, criando um relacionamento 1:N (Um Funcionário, várias MOVIMENTAÇÕES).

Sei fazer o relacionamento quando a tabela está vazia. Mas neste caso, como é um EVOLUTIVO,  a tabela MOVIMENTAÇÃO já possui registros. Na teoria, quando criasse a chave estrangeira, este campo poderia ficar null para os dados antigos. Porém, o dar o UPDATE-DATABASE, o SQL retorna o erro o seguinte erro:

> *The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.TB_MOVIMENTACAO_dbo.TB_FUNCIONARIO_Id_Funcionario". The
>   conflict occurred in database "FieldService_Desenv", table
>   "dbo.TB_FUNCIONARIO", column 'Id'.*

Como contorno este problema? O que vocês fazem neste caso?

Comment: Esta não é a resposta, e só um chute: talvez tenha de "desligar" a chave e "ligar" após ter alterado, não tenho certeza.

Comment: Não sei se percebi o seu problema pois julgo que a FOREIGN KEY pode ter nulos. Primeiro cria a coluna na tabela Movimentação e depois cria a FOREIGN KEY.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

São três passos.

## 1. Criar relacionamento permitindo nulo

A entidade `Movimentacao` ficaria assim:

```
public class Movimentacao
{
    public int MovimentacaoId { get; set; }
    public int? FuncionarioId { get; set; }

    // Coloque aqui os outros campos da sua movimentação

    public virtual Funcionario Funcionario { get; set; }
}
```

`Funcionario`, assim:

```
public class Funcionario 
{
    public int FuncionarioId { get; set; }

    // Coloque aqui os outros campos de seus funcionários

    public virtual ICollection<Movimentacao> Movimentacoes { get; set; }
}
```

Crie uma *Migration* através do **Package Manager Console**:

> Add-Migration FuncionariosMovimentacoes

Logo depois:

> Update-Database

Suba a alteração para o seu banco de dados.

## 2. Updates

Crie os funcionários e logo após crie as sentenças SQL que atualize `FuncionarioId` em `Movimentacoes`. Certifique-se de que nenhum `FuncionarioId` está nulo.

## 3. Modificar `FuncionarioId`

Altere `Movimentacao` tornando `FuncionarioId` não-nulo:

```
public class Movimentacao
{
    public int MovimentacaoId { get; set; }
    public int FuncionarioId { get; set; } // Deixou de ser int?

    // Coloque aqui os outros campos da sua movimentação

    public virtual Funcionario Funcionario { get; set; }
}
```

Crie mais uma *Migration*:

> Add-Migration MovimentacoesFuncionarioIdNaoNulo

Logo depois:

> Update-Database